# How to sort on text data type

Tags: sql, string, postgresql, sql-order-by

I have a table like below:

```
ID  | text_field
----| ----------
 1  | ABC-432
 2  | ABC-1
 3  | ABC-10
 4  | ABC-5
```

I would like to get a list of the top two results based on the `text_field` number part

Based on the above data the query output would be:

```
ID  | text_field
----| ----------
 1  | ABC-432
 3  | ABC-10
```

Since `432` and `10` are the two highest numbers in this data set.

Comment: Do all values start with `'ABC-'`? If not, please provide a variety of sample values that need to be catered for.

Comment: I think you need to normalize the table

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can take advantage of the flexibility of [Postgres string function `substring()`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.1/functions-string.html), that supports regular expressions.

```
SELECT *
FROM t
ORDER BY substring(val, '\d+$')::integer DESC
LIMIT 2
```

Regexp `'\d+$'` means : all digits at the end of the string. You need to cast it to an integer so you can perform a numerical sort.

**[Demo on DB Fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/i6xgqesE1z61uK1jd4XSGk/0)** :

```
| val     |
| ------- |
| ABC-432 |
| ABC-10  |
```